# PHP Search Engine with weights

Tags: php, search

I have to improve the search engine of my website.

Results must be sorted by performance.

For example : 
A user enter : "Jean Levis" in the input.
My search engine must assign a weight to all results by performance :

- +10 points because the category of the result if "Jeans"
- +5 points because the brand is "Levis"
- +5 points because is two miles from me
- etc...

So, how do you thing I can integrate that ? a big `mysql` script ?

Comment: hakre posts a nice & simple MySQL example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6496964/292735

Comment: massively complex code which usually takes very competent developers with a ligh level of maths understanding.  If you don't even know where to start chances are its something outside of your reach to achieve.  Hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: This requires a database, yes. I wouldn't call it "a big MySQL script" though, since non-trivial web applications are split over many files and libraries. To start this project, start designing the database, work out what tables you need, and how it should be normalised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Sphinx Search - it can do exactly what you need.

http://sphinxsearch.com/

If you can comiple your own MySQL, Sphinx can be integrated as another storage engine in MySQL database.

Start with this tutorial: 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-sphinxsearch/

Other tutorials are linked here: http://sphinxsearch.com/info/articles/

Comment: It seems to be awesone ! Have you got some great tutorials ? Thanks !

Comment: Added links to tutorials to response. Please accept answer.

Comment: Thanks Kacer ! I found this article too : http://atlchris.com/1996/working-with-sphinx-search-engine-on-a-lamp-linux-apache-mysql-and-php-stack-server/