# How to implement a more efficient search feature?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb.net

In my database there are 3 column which is Name, Age, Gender.
In the program, I only want to use 1 search button. When the button is clicked, the program determine which 3 of the textbox has input and search for the right data.

How do you work with the query? For example if Name and Gender has text, the query :

"`Select * from table Where (Name = @name) AND (Gender = @gender)`"

And when only name is entered, I only query for the name. Must I check textbox by textbox whether there is user input and then write multiple query for each of them? Or is there a better way to do this?

Edit (29/5/16) : I tried doing this another way like this

```
myCommand = New MySqlCommand("Select * from project_record Where
                       (FloatNo = @floatNo OR FloatNo = 'None') AND 
                       (DevCompanyName = @devCompanyName OR DevCompanyName = 'None') AND 
                       (DevType = @devType OR DevType = 'None') AND 
                       (LotPt = @lotPt OR LotPt = 'None') AND
                       (Mukim = @mukim OR Mukim = 'None') AND
                       (Daerah = @daerah OR Daerah = 'None') AND
                       (Negeri = @negeri OR Negeri = 'None') AND
                       (TempReference = @tempRef OR TempReference = 'None')", sqlConn)
```

But as you can guess already it will not work efficiently as well because if I only enter input for `DevType` and leave other textboxes blank, the query will not pull up all the records for `DevType` only. It will just display as no records.

Comment: it is much more better tactic to filter your results directly in your MySQL database. And if this is done with a simple query it is much more preferable! I have not seen any database schema but i think you must have set up indexes. @RickJames check out how to use `OR` in your query but still get single results if needed.

Comment: i really can't understand something... you use multiple AND's in your query. Why? You can query for getting both single and multiple results by using `OR`. One more thing i can't understand is this (i hope i am not lost in translation), this is from your question `In my database there are 3 column which is Name, Age, Gender. In the program, I only want to use 1 search button. When the button is clicked, the program determine which 3 of the textbox has input and search for the right data.` From the above i understand that if an input value is null or 0 to not participate in query results,right?

Comment: @PeterDarmis Yes correct. And that is why I put the AND clause because I am trying to make the query determine which textboxes has value then only search in the database. Also the column above is just an example. Not an actual column name in my program. My mistake for not clarifying it earlier

Comment: i was going to tell to check my answer but as i see, you already got votes for correct answers. Anyway do try the answer, i think it covers you better.

Comment: Will do! Thanks a lot too! Every answer counts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Original answer

(scroll down to see update)

Can you try the following:

- build a list only including values of the textboxes that have an input
- set a string of the join the items of that list together with the " AND " string
- append that string to your standard SELECT statement

The code looks like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Predicate1 As String = Me.TextBox1.Text
    Dim Predicate2 As String = Me.TextBox2.Text
    Dim Predicate3 As String = Me.TextBox3.Text
    Dim PredicateList As New List(Of String)
    Dim WhereClause As String
    Dim Query As String

    If Predicate1 <> String.Empty Then
        PredicateList.Add("Name=""" & Predicate1 & """")
    End If
    If Predicate2 <> String.Empty Then
        PredicateList.Add("Age=""" & Predicate2 & """")
    End If
    If Predicate3 <> String.Empty Then
        PredicateList.Add("Gender=""" & Predicate3 & """")
    End If

    WhereClause = String.Join(" AND ", PredicateList.ToArray)
    Query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE " & WhereClause
    MessageBox.Show(Query)

End Sub
```

### Update

Further to the comments re SQL injection, here is an updated sample.

```
Dim Command As SqlClient.SqlCommand
Dim Predicate1 As String = Me.TextBox1.Text
Dim Predicate2 As String = Me.TextBox2.Text
Dim Predicate3 As String = Me.TextBox2.Text
Dim ParameterList As New List(Of SqlClient.SqlParameter)
Dim PredicateList As New List(Of String)
Dim BaseQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE "

If Predicate1 <> String.Empty Then
    PredicateList.Add("name = @name")
    ParameterList.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@name", Predicate1))
End If
If Predicate2 <> String.Empty Then
    PredicateList.Add("age = @age")
    ParameterList.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@age", Predicate2))
End If
If Predicate3 <> String.Empty Then
    PredicateList.Add("gender = @gender")
    ParameterList.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@gender", Predicate3))
End If

Command = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(BaseQuery & String.Join(" AND ", PredicateList.ToArray))
Command.Parameters.AddRange(ParameterList.ToArray)
```

Comment: I did thought of this method too. But how would you know when to stop the AND at the end of which query? If only the last two textboxes have no input, the AND clause for the last two query would cause an error I think

Comment: Please try it out - wherever some TextBox is empty then it won't be included in the list. Therefore the join method on the list only includes the non-empty inputs.

Comment: It did works out well enough. Though I personally do not understand quite well about your predicatelist. Do you mind to explain more about it? Also I made some changes for the `If` statement because if the input is a blank space, the query will pull up wrong records.

Comment: Lists are collections from which you can add and remove items. For your requirements we are only adding non-empty items to the list. Once we have all the non-empty items we join them with the string " AND " and append to the SELECT. If you want to exclude items where the user accidentally input a space then use `If Trim(Predicate1) = String.Empty Then ...` etc

Comment: Thanks a lot. So far it is working fine from previous few debugging. I will continue to test it out further by continuing to add more of my original code and see how it goes. Once all is right I will accept your answer.

Comment: Also if I enter `"` as input, it will give out error. Does this mean it is vulnerable to sql injection attacks?

Comment: Yes it does.  Moreover, try to filter/find a name like `O'Brian` or `D'Artagnan` and it will crash.

Comment: @Plutonix So should I just remove the predicate1,2,... And replace it all with parameters string eg, $predicate1,$predicate2,... And using addwithvalue for those parameters?

Comment: I cant believe this is accepted answer! You should *NEVER* concatenate query text with user input! This is serious security vulnerability as it opens doors for SQL injections. *Always use parameters to pass values to the command!* Wake up people, it is 2016!!!

Comment: @KasparsOzols I accepted this answer because this answer gave me the idea and ways to overcome my problem. Issue like sql injections in this answer does not really matter to me because I know how to fix it myself. So basically I accepted this answer because it fix my problem. Nothing to do about sql injection problem.

Comment: @Student, I understand your reasons and this is great that you are just taking only good parts out of this, but there are so many people around that dont. They are blindly copy-pasting solutions and use in their code which goes into production. Answers like this make things like SQL injections still be around. This is very trivial error that should have been gone already by today. I would encorage answer owner to go and edit this answer and add parameters.

Comment: @KasparsOzols True. I am expecting the owner of this answer to fix the answer soon too. I just accept the answer based on what I questioned. So to the owner of the answer is responsible to amend his/her answer properly

Comment: Update in the answer

Answer (score 4):

```
Select * from table 
Where (Name = @name OR @name is Null) 
  AND (Gender = @gender OR @gender is Null)
 ...
```

it should be one query

Comment: Not sure why but the datagridview is not showing the records. Have a look here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36884228/vb-net-mysql-datagridview-is-empty)

Comment: you can also try **OR @gender = ''** just check what is sent to DB in case of empty textfield

Comment: It doesn't work. Lets say my textbox input for name is 'John'. The query will be `Name = John OR John is Null`.

Comment: yes. and what's wrong with this? if you use paratrized query. 'John' is null - false and name='John' is true. So the result all 'John' records are found

Comment: change the query to Name = John OR Name is Null

Answer (score 4):

Other answers have explained how to simplify the query.  It is especially important to get rid of the `ORs`, since they inhibit any use of indexes.

Once you have the query build cleanly, you need to think about the dataset and decide which columns are *usually* used for filtering.  Then make a few `INDEXes` for them.  You won't be able to provide 'all' possible indexes, hence my admonition that you think about the dataset.

When building indexes, you can have single-column or multiple-column indexes.  For your type of data, I would suggest starting with several 2-column indexes.  Make sure each index starts with a different column.

For `Where (Name = @name) AND (Gender = @gender)`, here are some notes:

```
INDEX(gender) is useless because of low 'cardinality';
INDEX(gender, name) might be useful, but the following would be better:
INDEX(name)
```

Things like `name` and `DevCompanyName` are virtually unique, so a 1-column index is probably good.

If you had `gender` and `age`, then `INDEX(age, gender)` *might* be useful.

MySQL will almost never use two indexes for a single `SELECT`.

By the way, the construction of the `WHERE` could be done in a Stored Procedure.  You would need `CONCAT`, `PREPARE`, etc.

Comment: What is INDEX and how does it work? Also what do you mean by stored procedure for the Where clause?

Comment: Cease all progress with databases until you read about "keys" and "indexes"!  They are vital to performance of SQL queries.

Comment: @RickJames couldn't have said it better!

Comment: @RickJames yes setting up a database with the correct keys,indexes,foreign keys etc is best practice and the initial database schema should be like that. But besides that simplifying a query to get the results we need even if we can't re-design the database is also needed sometimes. Additionally i can't understand why someone can't get results using `OR` between the fields???

Comment: The answer by iLikeMySql should work, but be slower than building the 'minimal' query, as Robin suggests.

Answer (score 2):

[COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) is your friend here. You can use it to make the where clause ignore comparisons where the parameter is NULL.

```
Select * from table Where (Name = COALESCE(@name,table.Name))
AND (Gender = COALESCE(@gender,table.Gender))
```

So, if the `@name` parameter is NULL, `COALESCE(@name,table.Name)` will return the value of the 'Name' column of the current row and `(Name = COALESCE(@name,table.Name))` will always be true.

This assumes that if no value is entered in a textbox the corresponding parameter will be NULL. If instead it is a value such as 'None', you can use the `NULLIF` function to map 'None' to NULL

```
Select * from table Where 
(Name = COALESCE( NULLIF( @name, 'None'), table.Name)) 
AND (Gender = COALESCE( NULLIF( @gender, 'None'), table.Gender))
```

Comment: What if the value entered is a blank space?

Comment: Trim the data of leading and trailing that comes in.  Otherwise "GIGO" -- Garbage In, Garbage Out.

Answer (score 1):

`How to implement a more efficient search?`

The answer partly depends on what your definition of *efficient* is.  I suspect you mean less code and fewer if blocks etc.  But fundamentally, running a new `SELECT *` query to apply a filter is inefficient because your base data set can be all the rows and you just fiddle with the users View of it.

I have a DB with random data in columns for *Fish*, *Color* (string), *Bird*, *Group* (int) and *Active* which should be similar enough for *Name*, *Age* and *Gender* in the question - or that other long thing at the bottom.

### DataTable

Fill a datatable and bind it to a DGV:

```vb
' form level object
Private dtSample As DataTable
...
' elsewhere
Dim sql = "SELECT  Id, Name, Descr, `Group`, Fish, Bird, Color, Active FROM Sample"
Using dbcon As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(MySQLConnStr)
    ' create SELECT command with the Query and conn
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, dbcon)
    ...
    daSample.Fill(dtSample)
    daSample.FillSchema(dtSimple, SchemaType.Source)
End Using
dgv2.DataSource = dtSample
```

Going forward, we can filter the user's ***view*** of that table *without* issuing a new query.

### Filter Controls

If some of the fields are limited to certain selections, for instance `Gender`, you can use a `ComboBox` instead of a `TextBox`.  This is to help the user succeed and avoid typos (*Make* or *Mael* instead of *Male*; or here, correctly spelling <strike>*Baracuda*</strike> I mean <strike>*Baraccuda*</strike>, er *Barracuda* correctly.

For illustration purposes, *Fish* is something where the user can type in anything at all, but *Bird* is constrained to a set of choices.  If there is a `Bird` table, `cboBird` can be bound or populated from it.  But you may also be able to populate it from the master/base table:

```vb
Dim birds = dtSample.AsEnumerable.Where(Function(d) d.IsNull(5) = False).
            Select(Function(d) d.Field(Of String)("Bird")).
            Distinct.
            ToArray()
cboBird.Items.AddRange(birds)
```

If "Finch" is a legal choice but there are none in the database, it wont show in the list.  Depending on the app, this can be a Good Thing:

- If the user filters on `Finch` and there a no resulting records, you won't need a `MessageBox` or `StatusBar` message explaining the empty result set.
- If something is not in the list, you are signalling *up front* that there are none of those.  It then becomes a matter of training why a known element isnt in the list.
- On the other hand, you'd have to repopulate those filter controls each time before they are used in case new records were added recently.  If the controls are on a `Dialog` or different `TabPage`, this is easy to do as needed.
- It isnt always applicable, but it can help the user avoid typos.

It depends on the app whether either method is of value.

### DBNull / 'none'

I am not sure why you are adding 'none' to each clause.  If someone want to see all the 'John` or all the 'Cod' records, it doesn't seem like they would also be interested in 'none'.  Personally, Null/DBNull seems a better way to handle this, but it is easy to add or not add either form.

It would seem *more* valuable to filter to *just those* with DBNull/None.  The code above for the Bird List filters out `DBNull` and I would do so for `none` as well.  Then, before the result is added to the `ComboBox`, add a `None' item first so it is at the top.

Again it depends on what the app does; `Or = 'None'`, may make perfect sense in this case.

### Filter

Using a `TextBox` for *Fish* and *Group*, a `ComboBox` for *Bird* and *Color* and a `CheckBox` for *Active*, the code can form the filter thusly:

```vb
Dim filterTerms As New List(Of String)
Dim filterFmt = "{0} = '{1}' "
'   OR:
' Dim filterFmt = "{0} = '{1}' OR {0} Is Null"
'   OR:
' Dim filterFmt = "{0} = '{1}' OR {0} = 'none'"
    
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbSearchFish.Text) = False Then
    Dim txt = tbSearchFish.Text.Replace("'", "''")
    filterTerms.Add(String.Format(filterFmt, "Fish", txt))
End If

If cboBird.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
    filterTerms.Add(String.Format(filterFmt, "Bird", cboBird.SelectedItem.ToString))
End If

If String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbGroup.Text) = False Then
    Dim n As Int32
    If Int32.TryParse(tbGroup.Text, n) Then
        filterTerms.Add(String.Format(filterFmt, "[Group]", n))
    End If
End If

If cboColor.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
    filterTerms.Add(String.Format(filterFmt, "Color", cboColor.SelectedItem.ToString))
End If

If chkActive.Checked Then
    ' NOTE: I do not have TreatTinyAsBoolean turned on
    '  for some reason
    filterTerms.Add(String.Format(filterFmt, "Active", "1"))
End If

If filterTerms.Count > 0 Then
    Dim filter = String.Join(" AND ", filterTerms)
    dtSample.DefaultView.RowFilter = filter

    Dim rows = dtSample.DefaultView.Count
End If
```

- Use whichever `filterFmt` is appropriate for what the app needs to do
- A filter term is only added to the list if the related control has a value (as per above, this could include a *'None'*).
- For the `TextBox`, it escapes any embedded ticks such as might be found in names like `O'Malley` or `D'Artgnan`.  It replaces one tick with two.
- Since *Group* is a numeric, a valid `Int32` input is tested
- If there are elements in the `filterTerms` list, a filter string is created
- The filter is applied to the `DefaultView.Filter`  (you can use also use a `DataView` or a `BindingSource`) so that **the code need not query the database to provide filter capabilities.**
- `Rows` will tell you how many rows are in the current View.

The only halfway tricky one is a Boolean like *Gender* or *Active* because those actually resolve to three choices: `{Any/Either, A, B}`.  For that, I would use a `ComboBox` and ignore it for SelectedIndex 0 as well.  I didn't bother with this because the `Combo` concept is amply covered.  Result:

[image]

## Is it More "Efficient"?

It still depends.
[image]  It doesn't re-query the database to get rows the app can already have.
[image] No new `DBConnection`, `DBCommand` or other DBProvider objects are created, just a list.
[image] No need to dynamically create a SQL statement with N parameters in a loop to avoid SQL injection/special words and chars.
[image]  It doesn't even query the database for the items for the filter terms.  If there is a static list of them in the DB, they could be loaded once, the first time they use the filters.
[image]  It is easy to remove the filter, no need to query yet again without `WHERE` clauses.
[image]  A `ComboBox` where applicable helps the user find what they want and avoid typos.
[image]  Is the SQL "cleaner". more "efficient?  The code doesn't really mess with new SQL, just some WHERE clauses.

Is there less code?  I have no idea since we just see the result.  It doesnt string me as a lot of code to do what it does.

Comment: Thanks so much for the expert answer. But I honestly do not get most part of it because I am still new and learning. Also, the application I am doing will be using by at least 3 different people and I want it to get latest updated records because one person maybe continuously entering records while another is searching for records..

Comment: Multiuser does not mean you need to requery the DB.   If you have a fully configured DataAdapter, `myDA.Fill(myDT)` will **refresh** the datatable getting any new rows added by others and remove those deleted by others **without** building a whole new query.  I suspected that there would be some knowledge gaps which is why there is lots of explanation there.  The filter code is pretty simple, add it to some test project to see how it works.

Comment: Think of the `.RowFilter` as magically adding a desired `WHERE` clause to the existing query - which is what it does.  If the datatable starts with all the rows, you just need to add the desired filter.  For multi-user, the only change would be to do `daSample.Fill(dtSample)` at the start to pick up any committed changes since the last time.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33702351/1070452) for setting up the DataAdapter to be smart

Comment: This in general isn't good for large tables depending on the data that you want coming back. For example we have a few system tables that store geospatial images that add up very quickly (1 tables is around 12 gigs) and therefore doing a select all upfront would be very costly and useless. Although the solution is good, but honestly depends on case by case.

Comment: If one could load everything in memory in one go, then he would not care about optimizing DB query as it would be blazingly fast anyways.

Comment: @KasparsOzols I believe the way the question is posed that the OP is talking about the way the code applies multiple filters from one button click.  Elsewhere, I was told 2k rows.

Answer (score 1):

> *In my database there are 3 column which is Name, Age, Gender. In the program, I only want to use 1 search button. When the button is clicked, the program determine which 3 of the textbox has input and search for the right data.*
>
> *And when only name is entered, I only query for the name. Must I check textbox by textbox whether there is user input and then write multiple query for each of them? Or is there a better way to do this?*

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE (`name` = @name AND `name` IS NOT NULL)
OR (`age` = @age AND (`age`>0 OR `age` IS NOT NULL))
OR (`gender` = @gender AND `gender` IS NOT NULL);
```

With the above query if all text boxes have value, the result will not be one record (as if you where using logical `AND` between fields). If you want only that record you will filter it server-side with php from the rest of the results.

You can check the results on your own in this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f3f7/1)

**EDIT**

In order to solve the above inconvenience (not bringing easily single results when needed) i got a little help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496866/best-way-to-do-a-weighted-search-over-multiple-fields-in-mysql) and re-wrote the above query as:

```
SELECT *, IF(`name`=@name, 10, 0) + IF(`age`=@age, 10, 0) + IF(`gender`=@gender, 10, 0) AS `weight` 
FROM `table` 
WHERE (`name` = @name AND `name` IS NOT NULL) 
OR (`age` = @age AND (`age`>0 OR `age` IS NOT NULL)) 
OR (`gender` = @gender AND `gender` IS NOT NULL) 
HAVING `weight`=30;
```

[image]
OR to still get all records with a `weight` on result

```
SELECT *, IF(`name`=@name, 10, 0) + IF(`age`=@age, 10, 0) + IF(`gender`=@gender, 10, 0) AS `weight` 
FROM `table` WHERE (`name` = @name AND `name` IS NOT NULL) 
OR (`age` = @age AND (`age`>0 OR `age` IS NOT NULL)) 
OR (`gender` = @gender AND `gender` IS NOT NULL) 
ORDER BY `weight` DESC;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close. Let's look at

```
(FloatNo = @floatNo OR FloatNo = 'None')
```

So you want the field either to be the given input or 'None'? But there are (supposedly) no records in your table with FloatNo  'None'. What you really want to do is find out whether the *input* is none (i.e. empty):

```
(FloatNo = @floatNo OR @floatNo = '')
```

And for the case the user types in a blank by mistake, you can ignore this, too:

```
(FloatNo = @floatNo OR TRIM(@floatNo) = '')
```

The whole thing:

```
myCommand = New MySqlCommand(
  "Select * from project_record Where
         (FloatNo = @floatNo OR TRIM(@floatNo) = '') AND 
         (DevCompanyName = @devCompanyName OR TRIM(@devCompanyName) = '') AND 
         (DevType = @devType OR TRIM(@devType) = '') AND 
         (LotPt = @lotPt OR TRIM(@lotPt) = '') AND
         (Mukim = @mukim OR TRIM(@mukim) = '') AND
         (Daerah = @daerah OR TRIM(@daerah) = '') AND
         (Negeri = @negeri OR TRIM(@negeri) = '') AND
         (TempReference = @tempRef OR TRIM(@tempRef) = '')", sqlConn)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with your approach?

Just change
(FloatNo = @floatNo OR FloatNo = 'None')
to
(FloatNo = @floatNo OR FloatNo = '' or FloatNo  IS NULL)

And do that for every criteria.
Your query will respect empty values and NULL values after that.