# PHP MySQL performance advice

Tags: php, mysql, database, loops

I have a table called `house`.

The table `house` has 32 columns (id, name, floors, doors, color, windows etc. etc.). So basically a table with different columns of different data types (varchar, int, decimal, enum and so on).

Now let's say the table has 500,000 rows.

And now I have my users. They can create a "house search" where they select all of the 32 columns what the search.

The "house search" gets also stored in another table `house_search`. I basically do a simple `INESRT INTO` with all the selected values.

While doing this I want to check if there is any "match" with the table `house`.

If I have a match I want to insert this match into another table `house_match`.

The problem is that I want to give points to the search so I cannot just simply create my SELECT to find the right rows.

To cut a long story short: What would be the best way to do the comparison of the given "house search" with all 500,000 rows?

Right now I store the "search" details in an MYSQLI_ASSOC array then select all houses and loop through each row and call a function which does the comparison.

Problem: very slow!

```
// Get the house search data
$sql = "SELECT columnsWeNeedForTheComparison
          FROM house_search
         WHERE id = ". $_POST['housesearchid'] .";";
$result = $mySQLi->query($sql); 
$searchHouse = $result->fetch_assoc();

$sql = "SELECT everyThingFromHouseTableWeNeed
          FROM house INNER JOIN ...
                     INNER JOIN ...;";
$result = $mySQLi->query($sql);
while($checkHouse = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
     // call comparison function
     $matchPoints = __checkHouseMatch($searchHouse, $checkHouse);

     if($matchPoints > 100)
     {
          $sql = "INSERT INTO house_match
                      ( ..... );";
          $insert = $mySQLi->query($sql);
     }
}
```

In function `__checkHouseMatch()` I do something like this

```
if($searchHouse['buildyear'] == $checkHouse['buildyear'])
{
    $matchPoints += 10;
}
else if($searchHouse['buildyear'] == $checkHouse['buildyear'])
{
    $matchPoints += 5;
}
```

If matchpoints is e.g. > 100 I do an `INSERT INTO` into `house_match`

```
 INSERT INTO house_match
     ( housesearchid, houseid )
 VALUES
     ( ". $houseSearchID .", ". $houseID ." );
```

What would be the best approach for this?

I could think about

- Storing all houses in an array?
- Cronjob at night where it doesn't matter how long it takes?

Any advice is highly appreciated!! Cheers :-)

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. Stack Overflow tries to steer away from general advice and focuses on specific technical problems that have concrete solutions.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Yes, I really know that! I am really sorry about that but here are so many professionals. Maybe one of them could give an advice :-) Lets please try!

Comment: add WHERE clause to seach, dont do it in php

Comment: 32 columns?? I would change the structure of that first.. add i.E. fk and create other table 'house details'

Comment: Cheers tadman! I also do use prepared statements. So all ob the above statements are prepared. For better understanding I chose to give the normal statements!

Comment: fwiw "weighted search". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496866/best-way-to-do-a-weighted-search-over-multiple-fields-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks pbalazek! I don't understand what would be the advantage? I only store simple values in the columns (doors=2, color=1 (which is a FK to table color), usedhouse=y and so on

Comment: Having built more than my fair share of real estate search sites, I can strongly recommend that you give up trying to do weighted searches in SQL (because they will never be fast enough) and instead push your data into a dedicated search engine like [Apache SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

Comment: Don't "dumb down" your code by inlining it and putting in obvious SQL injection bugs. Not only does it promote bad habits, it makes you look sloppy and casts immediate suspicion on the rest of your code. The only thing inlining stuff like that does for understanding is convey an understanding that you're playing with fire.

Comment: It also spurs people to exercise their comment macros enmasse.

Answer (score 0):

I think for what you're trying to do, the format of your table is wrong.

A table such as house_data: (id, house_id(FK), field, data) would work better. You'd also have another table called house: (id, ...) but not have the attributes such as windows, etc.

So on house_data you would have, for example:

```
id: 12
house_id: 30 (foreign key to house table)
field: windows
data: double-paned
```

I'm not recommending any particular indexing because I'm not sure if the focus of your searches is more related to the attributes of the house or the data in the attributes; that would make a difference.

Comment: Cheers Difster! Sounds good. Maybe I try this approach. Never thought about it. Will the table not be huge in the end? I have 500,000 houses x 32 "field rows" = 16.000.000 rows. Would it be really faster?

Comment: I think the search might be faster, yes. If you're going to query just windows for example, then it doesn't have to search through all the records, just the ones where field = "windows" and then the associated data.

When it comes to data, there's never one correct approach because of different use cases. However, I find that rather than store lots of different column names, I prefer this approach because then if I need to add to it, then I don't have to alter my table, just insert more data.

Comment: Sounds legit! I will definitely try this. Thanks for this!

Comment: Really though, with that kind of data set, you might want to try using Elastic Search along with the table format I suggested.